# Smart contract factory using an array of Struct as a parameter

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

I am using a CampaignFactory contract to create multiple instances of the Campaign contract and keep track of them. Every campaign is initialized with an array of Struct called rewards. When I try to create a new Campaign with createCampaign in remix, I have the following error:

```
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: CampaignFactory.createCampaign((uint256,uint256,string)[]) 0xd91...39138value: 0 weidata: 0x6d9...00000logs: 0hash: 0xa4d...ad5fd
transact to CampaignFactory.createCampaign errored: VM error: revert.
```

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

struct Reward {
    uint256 contribution;
    uint256 maxNumber;
    string ImageLink;
}

contract CampaignFactory {

    Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(Reward[] memory _rewards)
        public
    {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(msg.sender);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _rewards.length; i++) {
            newCampaign.createReward(
                _rewards[i].contribution,
                _rewards[i].maxNumber,
                _rewards[i].ImageLink
            );
        }
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns()
        public
        view
        returns (Campaign[] memory)
    {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}

contract Campaign {
    Reward[] public rewards;
    address public manager;

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    constructor(address creator) {
        manager = creator;
    }

    function createReward(
        uint256 _contribution,
        uint256 _maxNumber,
        string memory _imageLink
    ) public restricted {
        Reward memory newReward = Reward({
            contribution: _contribution,
            maxNumber: _maxNumber,
            ImageLink: _imageLink
        });

        rewards.push(newReward);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy the `Campaign` contract, the user's address is assigned to `manager`.

Then you're invoking the `createReward()` function. Its `restricted` modifier allows the function to be invoked only by the `manager`. But the function is invoked by your contract - not by the user directly. Which fails the validation and reverts the transaction.

---

You could get the address of the original transaction sender in `tx.origin`, but using it for authorization is a security risk - https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-115

So instead, you can pass the user address in the function argument, and verify it there.

```
function createCampaign(Reward[] memory _rewards)
    public
{
    // pass the factory address to later validate `msg.sender`
    Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(address(this), msg.sender);

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _rewards.length; i++) {
        // pass the user address to validate if they're the `manager`
        newCampaign.createReward(
            _rewards[i].contribution,
            _rewards[i].maxNumber,
            _rewards[i].ImageLink,
            msg.sender
        );
    }
    deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
}
```

```
address factory;
address public manager;

modifier restrictedThroughFactory(address user) {
    require(msg.sender == factory && user == manager);
    _;
}

modifier restricted() {
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
}

constructor(address _factory, address creator) {
    factory = _factory;
    manager = creator;
}

// original function that can be still executed directly by the user
function createReward(
    uint256 _contribution,
    uint256 _maxNumber,
    string memory _imageLink
) public restricted {
    _createReward(_contribution, _maxNumber, _imageLink);
}

// overloaded function that can be only executed by the Factory contract
// reverts if the `user` (can be passed only by the Factory contract) is not the `manager`
function createReward(
    uint256 _contribution,
    uint256 _maxNumber,
    string memory _imageLink,
    address user
) public restrictedThroughFactory(user) {
    _createReward(_contribution, _maxNumber, _imageLink);
}

function _createReward(
    uint256 _contribution,
    uint256 _maxNumber,
    string memory _imageLink
) internal {
    Reward memory newReward = Reward({
        contribution: _contribution,
        maxNumber: _maxNumber,
        ImageLink: _imageLink
    });

    rewards.push(newReward);
}
```